# Page_PreRenderComplete not firing in web control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

For some reason, the `Page_PreRenderComplete()` is not firing for me in a user web control. Here is my code behind, any ideas why?

```
    public partial class Views_CMSWebParts_GSAMetaTags : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
       public string Content { get; set; }
       public string LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
       public string PageTitle { get; set; }
       public string PageDescription { get; set; }

    protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (CMSContext.CurrentDocument.NodeClassName.Equals("ctv.DailyContent")
          || CMSContext.CurrentDocument.NodeClassName.Equals("ctv.Segment")
          ||  CMSContext.CurrentDocument.NodeClassName.Equals("ctv.segmentContainer"))
        {
            Content = "news-and-articles";

            //Published Date
            LastModifiedDate = ValidationHelper.GetString(CMSContext.CurrentDocument.GetValue("DocumentModifiedWhen"), "");

            PageTitle = CMSContext.CurrentPageInfo.DocumentPageTitle;
            PageDescription = CMSContext.CurrentPageInfo.DocumentPageDescription;

        }else if (CMSContext.CurrentDocument.DocumentName.Equals("Video"))
        {
            //using document name in this case becuase Video page type is Page (menu item)
            Content = "video";
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a UserControl has a PreRenderComplete event.  A Page does, but not a UserControl.  A UserControl does have a PreRender event, as well as a Render event.  You can use it like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.PreRender += new EventHandler([method name]);
}
```

Comment: This is obsolete in Framework 4.0 or higher. Now Page functions are called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in ASP.NET web forms now you have plenty of Page methods.

```
protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This will work for sure if your `Page_Load` function is called. You don't have to create events like in ASP.NET Framework 2.0 because now in new Framework 4.6 all Page life cycle events will be invoked automatically. Check your web form "something.aspx" page directives.